# Use aliases with cider in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

I am experimenting with [Chromex](https://github.com/binaryage/chromex) using `lein fig` and `lein content` aliases which runs smoothly in console but in cider's environment there is a direct call `(figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/start-figwheel!)` in script (not using an alias), which gives errors regarding `cljsbuild`.
My **question** is how to use alias in cider's environment (or there is other way around?).